# Google Sheets - QUERY - SUM() based on empty column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

[image: google sheets image]

I need to obtain the sum(B) if the column has empty values I want to reflect 0.
I am automating this process for multiple sheets using app-script and need to use QUERY.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear _why_ the use of `query()` is required. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with representative and _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `n()` to convert blanks to zeros, like this:

`=arrayformula( query( n(A2:B), "select sum(Col1), sum(Col2)", 0 ) )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `QUERY`, how about this formula in cell D1:

`={query(A2:A,"select sum(A) label sum(A) ''"),if(query(B2:B,"select count(B) label count(B) ''")=0,0,query(B2:B,"select sum(B) label sum(B) ''"))}`

An alternative would be:

`={sum(A:A),sum(B:B)}`

---

[image: screenshot]